# Convert characters to numeric

Tags: r

How can I convert characters to numeric values ?

```
 x <-c("0", "0,10", "18,20", "1,00")
```

I tried

```
 x <- as.numeric(x)
```

Without success

Output expected  a numeric vector :

```
0  
0.1  
18.2  
1
```

Comment: all elements have a trailing zero! what is your expected output actually?

Comment: If your data is read from a file, note the `dec` argument in `read.table` et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_replace(x, ",", "."))
#[1]  0.0  0.1 18.2  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```r
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x))

- output

str(as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
#>  num [1:4] 0 0.1 18.2 1
```

**data**

```
x <-c("0", "0,10", "18,20", "1,00")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
type.convert(c("0", "0,10", "18,20", "1,00"), as.is=TRUE, dec=',')
```

Comment: it seems `type.convert` can not deal with thousands separator